# How does HTML5 localstorage work?

Tags: html

I have to create one application in which the user is to get some data based on his username and passsword.

Is it possible to create single persistant local storage for multiple HTML pages of a website? Do I have to insert records everytime the page loads? My expectation is that inserting records one time for multiple users. Can anyone help?

Comment: Read up: http://diveintohtml5.org/storage.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, the storage is at domain level so you don't have to 'refresh' or re-populate the data on page load. It'll also survive sessions too, but remember that everything is a key/value pair **stored as a string** so you'll need to parse it when you read it back out (JSON.parse());

Comment: how can i do domain level storage like database in html5?becuase i have to add every confidential record manually in HTML5 page,how will it be called only one time?  will that records seen by users in browsers through viewsource code? anyhelp please?

Comment: Yes, if you go into the Chrome developer tools, on the resources panel there is a 'local storage' option. select that and you can see all the information stored locally on the machine. I guess you could use your own encryption/decryption if you wanted to obfuscate the data but there's no way to stop the user going in an tampering or deleting the data. It is, after all, on their own pc