# Setting a empty localStorage object results in "[object Object]"

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

I'm trying to save some data to `localStorage` within a containing object. If I were just using javascript variables, I would do this:

```
var obj = obj || {};
obj.fname = 'bob';
console.log(obj.fname) // => "bob"
```

However trying to do this in `localStorage`

```
window.localStorage.obj = window.localStorage.obj || {}
window.localStorage.obj.fname = 'bob';
console.log(window.localStorage.obj.fname) // => "[object Object]"
```

Why won't this same technique work for `localStorage`? Is there a way to do this?

Comment: `localStorage` can only store strings, so you have to serialize the object, e.g. using `JSON.stringify`.

Comment: Did you actually read his comment? @redneb post that as an answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to stringify the object and store it in localstorage.
Then when you need it you have to JSON.parse the json string.

```
var obj = {
   b : 2
};
window.localStorage.obj = JSON.Stringify(obj);
var returnObj = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.obj);
```

Answer (score 2):

localStorage can store only plain string so you need to

`window.localStorage.obj = JSON.stringify({fname: 'bob});`

Then for reading you need to parse it back so

`var obj = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.obj);
console.log(obj.fname);`

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7606853/how-does-html5-localstorage-work#answer-7609300) answer everything is stored in the localstorage in string format. Hence, in your case the `toString` method is being called on your `obj` before it is set. Setting completing objects in the localstorage under some key should be avoid. Try setting the value `bob` under a key `fname` in the localstorage using `localstorage.setItem('fname', 'bob')` or call `JSON.stringify` on `{fname: 'bob'}` before setting it in the `obj` key in the localstorage